# ¿Por que se cierra la app al momento de ejecutar el siguiente código?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema al ejecutar mi app desarrollada en Android Studio (v3.0.1) se cierra inesperadamente...
El código que ejecuto es el siguiente:

```
    int valor1, valor2, valor3;
    String mostrar;
    valor1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());
    valor2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString());
    if (r1.isChecked() == true)
    {
        valor3 = valor1 + valor2;
        mostrar = String.valueOf(valor3);
    }
    else if(r2.isChecked() == true)
    {
        valor3 = valor1 * valor2;
        mostrar = String.valueOf(valor3);
    }
    else
    {
        mostrar = "No";
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, mostrar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Nota: al borrar la declaración de las variables enteras y el uso de las mismas en el resto del código, se ejecuta correctamente.

> I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ImageView.setImageIcon, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageIcon
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16516: Landroid/widget/ImageView;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
>   W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415a6c50)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6680 SIG: 9
>   Application terminated.

Comment: Pero cual es error que se muestra en el Log de android studio?, Debes de proporcionar mas detalles para poder ayudarte

Comment: W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415a6c50)....
Y en el dispositivo me sale esto: "Disculpe Lamentablemente, la aplicación Appname se detuvo"

Comment: Pienso que el logcat provee mas lineas de las que muestras, edita tu pregunta y añade el log completo.

Comment: Bueno ahora lo hago... pero he estado moviendo y quitando cosas y creo que el error se encuentra en esta linea de código:

Comment: valor1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());

Tambien he tratado así:
 String a1 = t1.getText().toString();
 valor1 = Integer.parseInt(a1);

Pero también me cierra la app

Comment: El Log que acabas de agregar a la pregunta corresponde a la información del sistema, no al Log de la excepción (o Error), en el Logger Selecciona el nivel a Error, vuelve a ejecutar la aplicación y ahí aparecerá el error

Comment: El log dice que no encuntra setImageIcon ¿Estas usando este metodo en alguna parte del código que no pusiste?

Comment: no eso es de la misma app, pero no tiene nada que ver con el error

Comment: ademas no aparece ningún error

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en la conversión de string a int...

Comment: No lo creo, si crees que es así Intenta remplazar Integer.parseInt(), por Integer.valueOf(t1.getText().toString());, Creo que el error puede estar en los radioButton debido a que no están dentro de un RadioGroup, pero sin el log del error es demasiado difícil ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.. no estoy seguro de que es lo que esta pansand, pero corte y pegue el código y ya funciono

Comment: @josemarquez que bien, copiaste y pegaste tu propio código para que funcionara?, Ahora Comparte la respuesta para cerrar la pregunta

Comment: @josemarquez agrega el código donde usas setImageIcon para ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Primero como buena practica inicializa las variables.

```
int valor1 = 0, valor2 = 0, valor3 = 0;
String mostrar = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras no tiene relación con el mensaje de error.

> Could not find method android.widget.ImageView.setImageIcon,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageIcon

El problema en realidad es que no esta disponible el método [setImageIcon()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Icon))  en versiones menores a API Level 23, Android 6.0.